# Make texarea size not adjustable in google chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

By default, the size of textarea inputs in google chrome is adjustable in the browser.  Is there anyway to make it not adjustable?

Comment: Please, don't : that feature is really useful ; even if it might break the layout of your site, it will do so only for the user who resized the textarea *(i.e. user who knows what he's doing)*

Answer (score 22):

You can use this css for that:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

**[More Information Here. :)](http://brett.batie.com/?p=170)**